# Set Vertical Orientation to a LineEdit in Python qt

Tags: python, qt, qlineedit

I am making a GUI using qt and trying incorporate a LineEdit with Vertical Orientation.

When using the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(250, 250)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 120, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog #1", None))

class themain(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(themain,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit.setText('Some Text')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = themain()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get a simple LineEdit with Horizontal Orientation.

In essence I need something that looks like:
[Image][1]
http://users.ntua.gr/anthpro/images/dialog.png
(The image has been photoshopped to show the lineedit in vertical orientation)